# Laravel Route Model Binding: destroy method not grab necessary info

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Here is my controller for ProducerType model:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ProducerType;
use App\Http\Requests\ValidateProducerTypes;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProducerTypeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    ...

    public function destroy(ProducerType $producerType)
    {
        $producerType->delete();
        return redirect('/producers');
    }
}
```

And here is my model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProducerType extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome'
    ];
}
```

View:

```
<form action="/producers-type/{{ $type->id }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="btn-icon">
        <img src="{{ asset('images/times-circle-regular.svg') }}" alt="">
    </button>
</form>
```

Routes:

```
Route::resource('producers-type', 'ProducerTypeController', [
    'only' => ['store', 'update', 'destroy']
])->middleware('permission:create users');
```

My problem is: `$producerType` variable is not grabbing the necessaries attributtes.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A delete?

Comment: What attribute do you think it's not grabbing? The delete option just deletes the whole record, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: For delete you need to get an Instance which you're not getting.

`$producerType->delete();` $producerType here will be NULL so no delete will occur. You can fetch an instance by id first and then delete!

Comment: @Iftikharuddin This is what I'm trying to do. But `$producerType` is empty.

Comment: @marcelo2605 please share your view code!

Comment: @marcelo2605 also routes please :) I'm near to it :)

Comment: Specially delete route. I think your route is having  `delete/{id}` which should be `delete/producerType` Can you check it from `route:list`  command!

Comment: Here is the specific line on route list: `DELETE    | producers-type/{producers_type} | producers-type.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ProducerTypeController@destroy     | web,permission:create users,auth`

Comment: @Mozammil I try this way using this action without success. Even I accept an answer, I'm trying to make model binging works.

Comment: I don't know if it relevant, but I still have a route called `producers`

Answer (score 6):

Although the answer above gives a solution to the problem, I finnaly found the problem on my code!

From the Laravel documentation for [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding):

> Since the $user variable is type-hinted as the App\User Eloquent model
>   and the variable name matches the {user} URI segment, Laravel will
>   automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the
>   corresponding value from the request URI. If a matching model instance
>   is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP response will automatically
>   be generated.

This is my problem: I'm using `$producerType` variable and Laravel is expecting `$producers_type` because my route `producers-type/{producers_type}`.

Comment: Right check my comment 'Specially delete route. I think your route is having  `delete/{id}` which should be `delete/producerType` Can you check it from `route:list`  command!'

Comment: I'm using {add_product_log} in my route and using $addProductLog in my method and it works. I was originally just using AddProductLog $log, but it was missing attributes. AddProductLog $addProductLog works now. hope that helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
public function destroy(ProducerType $producerType)
{
    $producerType->delete();
    return redirect('/producers');
}
```

to

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $producerType = ProducerType::find($id);
    $producerType->delete();
    return redirect('/producers');
}
```

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: I think the problem is related the way I'm using Service Container.

Comment: @marcelo2605 check the update answer please! Also `dd($id` if it's coming or not!

Comment: This works. You know why I'm can't grabbing the id using Service Container?

Comment: @marcelo2605 don't know with this case. However I will have to try it myself! Glad to know it worked!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I believe using `$id` is not the better way, because user can change the value on DOM.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I'm studying the service container way :)